# An android OS level bug launcher activity launch always

Tags: android

When we install the application from source other than Google Play Store, then there are two options, Done and Open after installation finished. Then app's behavior is different in both cases. When we click on Done it works perfectly as expected but clicking on Open button the launcher activity is placed on the top of the activities stack every time app switches from background to foreground (even after application has been forcefully killed) when clicking on the app icon only and not from recent app tray.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to check whether the launcher activity is placed on top of the activities stack and clear the or finish the activity if it is on top of the stack-

```
Put below code on the onCreate() of launcher activity-

final Intent intent = getIntent();
if ((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT) != 0
        && intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
        && intent.getAction() != null
        && intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
    finish();// finish this launcher activity
    return;
}
```